# Multiple Instances of ASP.NET UserControl with query Autocomplete on same page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, webusercontrol

I'm quite new to jquery and javascript programming in general so please be patient.

I have an ASP.NET web user control (region.ascx) that contains an instance of the jquery autocomplete plugin. The jquery code (i have cutoff the code for brevity) is this:

```
$(function () {
    initializerRegion();
});

var prmInstance = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prmInstance.add_endRequest(function () {
    //you need to re-bind your jquery events here 
    initializerRegion();
});

function initializerRegion() {

    $($get('<%= autoRegion.ClientID %>')).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {..........................
```

The control works fine when there is only one instance of the control on an asp.net page. I have a situation where I have two separate user controls (Org.ascx and Place.ascx) that each have an instance of region.ascx that are on a single asp.net page, therefor i end up with 2 instances of the above code. When this is the case only the last instance (for place.ascx) is initialized correctly and works. The other instance (org.ascx) doesn't do anything.

I think I may be able to get around this by putting the Initializer code above into each of the controls that needs it, essentially getting rid of my region.ascx control. I have a feeling that if I do this and make the names of the initializer functions unique it may work.

My question is: Am I doing this correctly? Is there a way around this?

Comment: You reveal too little of your code to give a good answer. You need not repeat the same code in two different functions, you only need to be sure that you function takes the ClientIDs of where to show the autocomplete correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `prmInstance` variable and `initializerRegion` function declared in global execution context. So the last control overrides `initializerRegion` function definition. To fix this you may wrap all your code in self called function like below:

```
(function () {
    var prmInstance = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prmInstance.add_endRequest(function () {
        //you need to re-bind your jquery events here 
        initializerRegion();
    });

    var initializerRegion = function () {
        $('#<%= autoRegion.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                //......
            },
            //......
        });

        $(function () {
            initializerRegion();
        });
    })();
```

This code works well for me:

ascx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var prmInstance = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prmInstance.add_endRequest(function () {
            initialize();
        });

        var initialize = function () {
            $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").on("keyup", function () {
                alert(this.value);
            });
        };

        $(function () {
            initialize();
        });
    })();
</script>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />
```

aspx:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <uc:WebUserControl2 runat="server" ID="ucWebUserControl2" />
        <asp:Button Text="Click Me" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<hr />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <uc:WebUserControl2 runat="server" ID="WebUserControl1" />
        <asp:Button Text="Click Me" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Hey Yuriy, thanks for the reply but unfortunately wrapping the code in self called function as you suggested did not work. In-Fact, when doing this the jquery autocomplete plug-in doesn't get wired to my input control and never get's fired. I have also tested this in a simple scenario where i know i have only one instance of the code on my page with the same result

Comment: Check you code, because this must work. See updated answer with sample.

Comment: Hey Yurly, after using your posted code as a guide i managed to get this to work. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
$(function () {
    initializerRegion();
});
```

Is the root of your problem. This translates to $document.Ready() which can be handled only once. So instead of having this region at your user control level, it should **always** be at page level. In the mentioned scenario you have two instances of the same user control, but instead of that if you had two separate user controls with the similar initialization, your code would have still failed.

Place the above code in the page in which the user controls are added and your code should work fine.

Let me know whether this works for you or not.

Comment: Hey @avanigadhai, thanks for the input but this doesn't work. when trying this solution on a page with a single instance of the user control it works (as did my original code) but when used when multiple instances of the control are on a page this, like my orignial code, only works on the second instance on the page.

Comment: Hi @JustinCale, can you modify the selector <code>$($get('<%= autoRegion.ClientID %>'))</code> to class selector? By class selector I mean, your <code>autoRegion</code> should look like <code> < ID="autoRegion" class="someClass" ../></code> and the JQuery code should look like <code>$(".someClass')</code>. Let me know this works or not for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery instead of asp.nettoolkit autocomplete and it will allow you use as many automplete that you want

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txtBoxWord").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "AutoComplete.asmx/GetCompletionList",
                    data: "{ 'prefixText': '" + request.term + "','count':'10',contextKey:" + comboboxLang.GetSelectedIndex() + " }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("width", "340px");
                        if (comboboxLang.GetSelectedIndex() == 0) {
                            $(".ui-autocomplete").css("direction", "ltr");
                        }
                        if (comboboxLang.GetSelectedIndex() == 1) {
                            $(".ui-autocomplete").css("direction", "rtl");
                        }
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1

        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is a good example 
[Three different way of using jquery autocomplete with asp.net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/78704/3-Different-Approaches-for-Implementing-the-JQuery)

Comment: Hi @Danare, I am using jquery autoComplete. Can you please explain what you mean when you say i can use many autocmpletes?

Comment: I mean when you have multiple controls that you can use apply autocompelete on them each one seperately