# Web user control stops working when we use multipul instance at one page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, web-user-controls

I am developing a multi-column combo-box using Ajax and asp controls.My control works fine when we use one instance at a page.But stops working when we use multiple instance on one page.

## ascx code

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="BssWebDataCombo.ascx.cs" Inherits="BssWebDataCombo" ClientIDMode="Predictable"  %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxControl" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="GridViewCSSThemes/YahooGridView.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<%--Mouse hover start--%>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var backcolorselect = "orange";
    var backcolorfirstrow = "#F5F5F5";
    var backcoloralternetrow = "#CCDDFB";
    function MouseEvents(objRef, evt) {
        //var checkbox = objRef.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
        if (evt.type == "mouseover") {
            objRef.style.backgroundColor = backcolorselect; //"orange";
        }
        else {
            if (objRef.rowIndex % 2 == 0) {
                //Alternating Row Color
                objRef.style.backgroundColor = backcoloralternetrow; // "#9AD8ED";
            }
            else {
                objRef.style.backgroundColor = backcolorfirstrow; // "white";
            }
        }
    }

</script> 
<%--Mouse hover end--%>

<%--Set dropdown visibility start--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //dropdown arrow key allways visible
    function VisibleMe() {
        $find('<%= DDE.ClientID%>')._dropWrapperHoverBehavior_onhover();
    }

    //Row selection using arrow key
    var SelectedRow = null;
    var SelectedRowIndex = null;
    var UpperBound = null;
    var LowerBound = null;
    function SelectValue(CurrentRow, RowIndex) {
        document.getElementById('<%= txtDisplay.ClientID%>').value = (CurrentRow.cells[1].innerHTML == "" ? CurrentRow.cells[2].innerHTML : CurrentRow.cells[1].innerHTML);

        closeDatacombo();
    }
    function SelectRow(CurrentRow, RowIndex) {
        document.getElementById('<%= txtSearch.ClientID%>').value = "";
        if (SelectedRow == CurrentRow || RowIndex > UpperBound || RowIndex < LowerBound) return;
        if (SelectedRow != null) {
            if (SelectedRow.style.backgroundColor == backcolorselect) { //"orange") {

            }
            else {
                SelectedRow.style.backgroundColor = SelectedRow.originalBackgroundColor;
                SelectedRow.style.color = SelectedRow.originalForeColor;
            }
            if ((SelectedRowIndex + 1) % 2 == 0) {
                //Alternating Row Color
                SelectedRow.style.backgroundColor = backcoloralternetrow; //"#9AD8ED";
            }
            else {
                SelectedRow.style.backgroundColor = backcolorfirstrow; //"white";
            }
        }

        if (CurrentRow != null) {
            CurrentRow.originalBackgroundColor = CurrentRow.style.backgroundColor;
            CurrentRow.originalForeColor = CurrentRow.style.color;
            CurrentRow.style.backgroundColor = backcolorselect; //"orange"//'#DCFC5C';
            CurrentRow.style.color = 'Black';
        }

        SelectedRow = CurrentRow;
        SelectedRowIndex = RowIndex;
        document.getElementById('<%= Hidden_RowIndex.ClientID%>').value = RowIndex;
        setFooter();
        setTimeout("SelectedRow.focus();", 0);
    }

    //Select next row
    function SelectSibling(e) {
        var e = e ? e : window.event;
        var KeyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        var cntrlname = document.getElementById('<%= gridEdit.ClientID%>');
        var rows = cntrlname.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        //alert(SelectedRowIndex + '\r\n' + rows.length);
        if (KeyCode == 40) {
            if ((SelectedRowIndex + 1) < rows.length) {
                SelectRow(SelectedRow.nextSibling, SelectedRowIndex + 1);
            }
            else {
                SelectRow(SelectedRow, SelectedRowIndex);
            }
        }
        else if (KeyCode == 38) {
            SelectRow(SelectedRow.previousSibling, SelectedRowIndex - 1);
        }
        else if (KeyCode == 13) {
            SelectedRow.style.backgroundColor = backcolorselect; //"orange";
            SelectValue(SelectedRow, SelectedRowIndex);
        }
        else if (KeyCode == 9) {
            SelectedRow.style.backgroundColor = backcolorselect; //"orange";
            SelectValue(SelectedRow, SelectedRowIndex);
        }
        return false;
    }
    //Ragister on page load
    var DDE;
    function ShowMe() {
        DDE._wasClicked = true;
    }

    //Show datacombo on textbox focus
    function showDataCombo() {
        var d = $get('<%= txtDisplay.ClientID%>');
        d.click();
        if (document.getElementById('<%= divGrid.ClientID%>').scrollHeight > 615) {
            document.getElementById('<%= Table1.ClientID%>').style.width = "983px";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('<%= Table1.ClientID%>').style.width = "1000px";
        }
        afterpostback();
        setFooter();
        document.getElementById('<%= txtSearch.ClientID%>').focus();
    }

    // Add handler for event DropDownExtender.hiding
    // This will cancel hiding the dropdown so we can type in the postcode
    function TextBox1_focus() {
        var dde = $find('<%= DDE.ClientID%>')
        dde.add_hiding(DDE_Hiding);
    }

    // Remove handler for event DropDownExtender.hiding
    function TextBox1_blur() {
        var dde = $find('<%= DDE.ClientID%>')
        dde.remove_hiding(DDE_Hiding);
    }

    function DDE_Hiding(e) {
        e.set_cancel(true);
    }

</script>  
<%--Set dropdown visibility end--%>

<%--Search in gridview start--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    String.prototype.startsWith = function (str) { return (this.indexOf(str) === 0); }
    function Highlight() {
        var srchval = document.getElementById('<%= txtSearch.ClientID%>').value;
        var cntrlname = document.getElementById('<%= gridEdit.ClientID%>');
        var rows = cntrlname.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var rowTop = 0;
        var FirstRow = rows[1];
        for (var loop = 0; loop < rows.length; loop++) {
            if (loop != SelectedRowIndex) {
                if (loop % 2 != 0) {
                    //Alternating Row Color
                    rows[loop].style.background = backcoloralternetrow; //"#9AD8ED";
                }
                else {
                    rows[loop].style.background = backcolorfirstrow; //"white";
                }
            }
            else {
                rows[loop].style.background = backcolorselect; //"orange";
            }
        }
        var ok = 0;
        if (srchval != '') {
            do {
                for (var loop = 0; loop < rows.length; loop++) {
                    var cells = rows[loop].getElementsByTagName("td");
                    if (ok != 2) {
                        for (i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                            if (cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().startsWith(srchval.toLowerCase())) {
                                ok = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (ok == 1) {
                        CurrentRow = rows[loop];
                        CurrentRow.style.background = backcolorselect; //'orange';
                        SelectedRow = CurrentRow;
                        SelectedRowIndex = loop;
                        document.getElementById('<%= Hidden_RowIndex.ClientID%>').value = loop;
                        document.getElementById('<%= divGrid.ClientID%>').scrollTop = loop * CurrentRow.clientHeight;
                        var h = document.getElementById('<%= hfScrollPosition.ClientID%>');
                        h.value = loop * CurrentRow.clientHeight;
                        setFooter();
                        ok = 2;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (loop % 2 != 0) {
                            //Alternating Row Color
                            rows[loop].style.background = backcoloralternetrow; //"#9AD8ED";
                        }
                        else {
                            rows[loop].style.background = backcolorfirstrow; //"white";
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (srchval.length > 0) {
                    srchval = srchval.substring(0, srchval.length - 1);
                }
            } while (ok == 0 && srchval.length > 0);
        }
        if (SelectedRowIndex <= -1) {
            if (srchval.length <= 0 || ok == 0) {
                CurrentRow = rows[0];
                CurrentRow.style.background = backcolorselect; //'orange';
                SelectedRow = CurrentRow;
                SelectedRowIndex = 0;
                document.getElementById('<%= Hidden_RowIndex.ClientID%>').value = 0;
                document.getElementById('<%= divGrid.ClientID%>').scrollTop = 0 * CurrentRow.clientHeight;
                var h = document.getElementById('<%= hfScrollPosition.ClientID%>');
                h.value = 0 * CurrentRow.clientHeight;
                setFooter();

                for (var loop = 0; loop < rows.length; loop++) {
                    if (loop != SelectedRowIndex) {
                        if (loop % 2 != 0) {
                            //Alternating Row Color
                            rows[loop].style.background = backcoloralternetrow; //"#9AD8ED";
                        }
                        else {
                            rows[loop].style.background = backcolorfirstrow; //"white";
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        rows[loop].style.background = backcolorselect; //"orange";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function SendUp(CurrentRow, FirstRow) {
        FirstRow.parentNode.insertBefore(CurrentRow, FirstRow);
    }
    function GetMedName(MedName) {
        document.getElementById('<%= txtSearch.ClientID%>').value = MedName;
    }

    function setFocusOnGrid(evt, id) {
        var evt = evt ? evt : window.event;
        var KeyCode = evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        var cntrlname = document.getElementById('<%= gridEdit.ClientID%>');
        var rows = cntrlname.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        if (SelectedRowIndex < rows.length) {
            if (KeyCode == 40) {
                SelectRow(rows[parseInt(SelectedRowIndex) + 1], parseInt(SelectedRowIndex) + 1);
            }
            else if (KeyCode == 38) {
                SelectRow(rows[parseInt(SelectedRowIndex) - 1], parseInt(SelectedRowIndex) - 1);
            }
            else if (KeyCode == 13) {
                //alert(KeyCode);
                SelectedRow.style.backgroundColor = backcolorselect; //"orange";
                SelectValue(rows[SelectedRowIndex], SelectedRowIndex);
                return false;
            }
            else if (KeyCode == 9) {
                if (SelectedRowIndex == -1) {
                    SelectedRowIndex = 0;
                    SelectedRow = rows[0];
                    rows[0].style.backgroundColor = backcolorselect; // "orange";
                    SelectValue(rows[0], 0);
                }
                else {
                    SelectedRow.style.backgroundColor = backcolorselect; // "orange";
                    SelectValue(rows[SelectedRowIndex], SelectedRowIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    function setFocusOnSearch(event) {
        if (event.altKey == false && event.ctrlKey == false) {
            if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57 && event.shiftKey == false) ||
            (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) ||
            (event.keyCode >= 97 && event.keyCode <= 122)) {
                document.getElementById('<%= txtSearch.ClientID%>').value = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
                document.getElementById('<%= txtSearch.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<%--Search in gridview end--%>

<%--Maintain scroll position start--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetDivPosition() {
        var intY = document.getElementById('<%= divGrid.ClientID%>').scrollTop;
        var h = document.getElementById('<%= hfScrollPosition.ClientID%>');
        h.value = intY;
    }

    function afterpostback() {
        var h = document.getElementById('<%= hfScrollPosition.ClientID%>');
        document.getElementById('<%= divGrid.ClientID%>').scrollTop = h.value;
    }
</script>
<%--Maintain scroll position end--%>

<%--Supporting function start--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Set footer description
    function setFooter() {
        var cntrlname = document.getElementById('<%= gridEdit.ClientID%>');
        var rows = cntrlname.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        if (SelectedRowIndex != -1) {
            document.getElementById('<%= lblTot.ClientID%>').value = 'Record: ' + (parseInt(SelectedRowIndex) + 1) + ' / ' + rows.length;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('<%= lblTot.ClientID%>').value = 'Record: ' + rows.length;
        }
    }

    function closeDatacombo() {
        var cntrlname = document.getElementById('<%= gridEdit.ClientID%>');
        var rows = cntrlname.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        if (SelectedRow != null) {
            document.getElementById('<%= txtDisplay.ClientID%>').value = (SelectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML == "" ? SelectedRow.cells[2].innerHTML : SelectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML);
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('<%= txtDisplay.ClientID%>').value = (rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML == "" ? rows[0].cells[2].innerHTML : rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML);
            SelectedRowIndex = 0;
            SelectedRow = rows[0];
        }
        rows[SelectedRowIndex].style.backgroundColor = backcolorselect;
        var hidden = $get('<%= Hidden1.ClientID%>');
        hidden.click();
        document.getElementById('<%= gridEdit.ClientID%>').nextSibling.focus();
    }
</script>
<%--Supporting function end--%>

<%--Add page load event start--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function control1OnLoadHandler() {
        //Maintain scroll position
        var h = document.getElementById('<%= hfScrollPosition.ClientID%>');
        document.getElementById('<%= divGrid.ClientID%>').scrollTop = h.value;

        //dropdown arrow key allways visible.
        $find('<%= DDE.ClientID%>')._dropWrapperHoverBehavior_onhover();
        $find('<%= DDE.ClientID%>').unhover = VisibleMe;

        //Show and hide panal on mouse over anf leave
        //var dxt = $find('DDE');
        //var panel = $get('DropPanel');
        //var hidden = $get('Hidden1');

        //$addHandler(dxt.get_element(), "mouseover", function () { dxt.show(); });
        //$addHandler(dxt.get_element(), "mouseleave", function () { hidden.click(); });
        //$addHandler(panel, "mouseleave", function () { hidden.click(); });
        //$addHandler(panel, "mouseover", function () { dxt.show(); });

        //Row selection using arrow key
        UpperBound = parseInt('<%= this.gridEdit.Rows.Count %>') - 1;
        LowerBound = 0;
        SelectedRowIndex = (document.getElementById('<%= Hidden_RowIndex.ClientID%>').value.length > 0 ? document.getElementById('<%= Hidden_RowIndex.ClientID%>').value : -1);

        DDE = $find('<%= DDE.ClientID%>');
        DDE._dropWrapperHoverBehavior_onhover();
        $get('<%= DropPanel.ClientID%>').style.width = $get('<%= txtDisplay.ClientID%>').clientWidth;


        if (DDE._dropDownControl) {
            $common.removeHandlers(DDE._dropDownControl, DDE._dropDownControl$delegates);
        }
        DDE._dropDownControl$delegates = {
            click: Function.createDelegate(DDE, ShowMe),
            contextmenu: Function.createDelegate(DDE, DDE._dropDownControl_oncontextmenu)
        }
        $addHandlers(DDE._dropDownControl, DDE._dropDownControl$delegates);

        var cntrlname = document.getElementById('<%= gridEdit.ClientID%>');
        var rows = cntrlname.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        rows[SelectedRowIndex].style.backgroundColor = backcolorselect; // "orange";
    }
    function addLoadEventHandler(func) {
        var previous_handler = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != "function") window.onload = func;
        else window.onload = function () {
            previous_handler();
            func();
        }
    }
    //add this control's onLoad handler to the document's onload, without
    //replacing whatever handler may be there already
    addLoadEventHandler(control1OnLoadHandler);
</script>

<%--Control designer start--%>
<div style="position:relative;border:none;">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden1" Value="" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden_RowIndex" Value="" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfScrollPosition" Value="" runat="server" />
    <%--<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDisplay" runat="server" onfocus="showDataCombo();" CssClass="tb10" ToolTip="Type for search"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Panel ID="DropPanel" runat="server" CssClass="ContextMenuPanel" Width="1000px"
                    style="display :none; 
                        visibility: hidden;
                        border:2px solid #E5E5E5;
                        padding-bottom:-1px;
                        margin-top:-28px;
                        background-color:#83ACF3;
                        overflow:hidden;
                        height:auto;
                        max-height:700px;">
                    <div class="ddeSerch">
                        <div style="padding-top:5px;float:left;">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;Look-Up&nbsp;
                        </div>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" CssClass="tb10" BackColor="White" Width="470px" MaxLength="150"
                            onkeypress="Highlight()" 
                            onblur="return Highlight()" 
                            onkeydown="return setFocusOnGrid(event, this.id)"
                            onkeyup="Highlight()"
                            onclick="return false;"
                            style="background: url(GridViewCSSThemes/Images/tia.png) no-repeat top right;background-color:White;padding-right:25px;">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                        <div style="padding-top:5px;float:right;cursor:pointer;" onclick="closeDatacombo();">
                            Close
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" CssClass="header" GridLines="Vertical" Width="983px">
                    </asp:Table>
                    <%--<z>--%>
                        <div id="divGrid" runat="server" onscroll="SetDivPosition()" style="max-height:615px;width:100%;overflow-X:auto;overflow-Y:auto;">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gridEdit" GridLines="Vertical" runat="server" Width="100%" 
                                ShowFooter="false" ShowHeader="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                                Font-Size = "11pt" Font-Names = "Arial"  style="color:Black;"
                                AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#CCDDFB" 
                                RowStyle-BackColor="WhiteSmoke"
                                onkeydown="return setFocusOnSearch(event)"
                                OnRowCreated="gridEdit_RowCreated" OnRowDataBound="gridEdit_RowDataBound" >
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No.">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex + 1%>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Bold="false" />
                                <RowStyle CssClass="rowstyle"/>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                    <%--</z>--%>
                    <table class="footer" id="tblfooter" runat="server">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:left;">
                                <asp:TextBox Enabled="false" ID="lblOrd" CssClass="footer" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:right;">
                                <asp:TextBox Enabled="false" ID="lblTot" CssClass="footer" style="text-align:right;" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
                <ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender runat="server" ID="DDE"
                    TargetControlID="txtDisplay"
                    DropDownControlID="DropPanel" />
        <%--</ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>--%>
</div>
<%--Control designer end--%>
```

### Server side code

```
public partial class BssWebDataCombo : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    internal Dictionary<string, int> _dcmbColWidth;
                                                                        public Dictionary<string, int> dcmbColWidth
{
    get
    {
        if (_dcmbColWidth == null)
        {
            _dcmbColWidth = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            _dcmbColWidth.Add("S.No.", 7);
            _dcmbColWidth.Add("ID", 4);
            _dcmbColWidth.Add("Name", 35);
            _dcmbColWidth.Add("Age", 14);
            _dcmbColWidth.Add("City", 20);
            _dcmbColWidth.Add("Contact", 20);
        }
        return _dcmbColWidth;
    }
    set { _dcmbColWidth = value; }
}

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, this.GetType(), "CallJS", "pageLoad();afterpostback();", true);
        }
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Contact", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns["ID"].AutoIncrement = true;
            dt.Columns["ID"].AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
            dt.Columns["ID"].AutoIncrementStep = 1;
            dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["ID"] };
            dt.Rows.Add(null, "Ashish Rathore", "27", "Dewas", "9826825190");
            dt.Rows.Add(null, "Mohan Pawanr", "27", "Ujjain", "9826825111");
            dt.Rows.Add(null, "Raja Mohan", "27", "Bhopal", "9826825111");
            dt.Rows.Add(null, "Kamlesh", "27", "Dewas", "9826825111");
            dt.Rows.Add(null, "Pawan", "27", "Indore", "9826825111");
            dt.Rows.Add(null, "Mohit", "27", "Dewas", "9826825111");
            dt.Rows.Add(null, "Sohan", "27", "Dewas", "9826825111");

            if (gridEdit.Columns.Count > 0)
            {
                while (gridEdit.Columns.Count > 1)
                {
                    gridEdit.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
                }
            }
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                //Declare the bound field and allocate memory for the bound field.
                BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
                //Initalize the DataField value.
                //bfield.DataField = col.ColumnName;
                //Initialize the HeaderText field value.
                bfield.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;
                bfield.DataField = col.ColumnName;
                //Add the newly created bound field to the GridView.
                gridEdit.Columns.Add(bfield);
            }


            dt.DefaultView.Sort = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;
            gridEdit.DataSource = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
            gridEdit.DataBind();

            lblTot.Text = "Records: " + dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
            lblOrd.Text = "Order: " + dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;
        }
        if (gridEdit.Columns.Count > dcmbColWidth.Count)
        {
            gridEdit.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        int x = 0;
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        foreach (var dc in dcmbColWidth)
        {
            if (dc.Key != "ID")
            {
                tc = new TableCell();
                tc.Text = dc.Key;
                tc.Attributes.Add("width", dc.Value + "%");
                tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            }
            gridEdit.Columns[x].ItemStyle.Width = Convert.ToInt16((DropPanel.Width.Value * Convert.ToDouble(dc.Value)) / 100);
            x++;
        }
        Table1.Rows.Add(tr);

        gridEdit.Columns[1].Visible = false;
    }

    #region Record View (Common Gridview Events)
    protected void gridEdit_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Normal || e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate))
        {
            e.Row.TabIndex = -1;
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("javascript:SelectRow(this, {0});", e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.Attributes["ondblclick"] = string.Format("javascript:SelectValue(this, {0});", e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.Attributes["onkeydown"] = "javascript:return SelectSibling(event);";
            e.Row.Attributes["onselectstart"] = "javascript:return false;";
            //e.Row.Attributes["onblur"] = string.Format("javascript:SelectValue(this, {0});", e.Row.RowIndex);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Java-script of my web user control stops working on multiple instance.
Can any one tell me how can i modify my script for working on multiple instance.

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work.

Comment: I mean to say that when i use more then one instance of this control on one page it overwrites js functions.Because of that control stops working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14974845/360171

Comment: Please consider excerpting your code and stripping down your failure to a very simple case.

Comment: this problem is solved by passing control id's as parameters into java-script function from server side code.And now my control works fine even with multi instance on one page.But still i am having one problem i need to set visibility of dropdown-extender panel to true for that i need to do this on form load.But it works only for last control of form.I mean to say that last control's onload script over-rights all all controls onload script.Can you tell me how can i deal with this situation.